# How to use a R seed in python for kmeans

Tags: python, r, k-means, seed

Im writing a project using the kmeans algorithm in python. I need to reproduce the result of a partner who is using R, with the seed "123"

Is there anyway to use the R seed in python for the kmeans function?

I tried to use:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances_argmin_min
%matplotlib inline
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16, 9)
plt.style.use('ggplot')

df = pd.read_excel(r'E:\Superservicios\Modelo de riesgo\Escenarios\Base_indicadores.xlsx')
df.head()

X = np.array(df[["ACTIVO","INGRESOS"]])

data = robjects.r("""
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(4)
""")

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state = data).fit(X)
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
print(centroids)
```

But i get the error

<rpy2.robjects.vectors.FloatVector object at 0x0000019B76DB5500> [RTYPES.REALSXP]
R classes: ('numeric',)
[0.287578, 0.788305, 0.408977, 0.883017] cannot be used to seed a numpy.random.RandomState instance

I´m new using python and stackoverflow, I would be very grateful to receive your help

Thanks.

Comment: Would you like to use the current state of the seed or the result vector of the R script?

Comment: Can you print value of data variable? Based on the error message it should be an array. However Kmeans function expect an integer as its random_state argument: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans